# How to upload a file to FTP server using Visual C++

Tags: ftpwebrequest, visual-c++-2010

I am writing an application that aims to upload file from local system to FTP server using predefined Ftp credentials using Visual C++ 2010.

I haven't find proper help via google.

Kindly advise me with a solution or work around.

Answer (score 0):

Look for "libcurl" - among other things, it also implements FTP.